# how to get total price of books django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

if i add some books in store then how can i get the total_price of selected books in store?

signals are not working they are not [calculating anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvssS.png). i want to calculate the [selected books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTRx6.png). after submitting the form i got nothing in total price is [still (0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvssS.png).

[signals.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6mDw.png)

[models.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG4vl.png)

store

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Store(models.Model):     
    keeper = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Store
from .models import Book


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Store)
def save_total_price(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.total = Book.objects.all().aggregate(Sum("price"))["price__sum"]
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ReportConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'report'

    def ready(self):
        import report.signals
```

**init**.py

```
default_app_config = "report.apps.ReportAppConfig"
```

Comment: u don't need to override save method just create a function decorated with @property and use the same aggregate logic to return a value

Comment: yeah i have to try this function would you like to suggest me how can i define this function and solve this error?

Comment: Are you sure you need to store it in the db? You can also  add a method `Store` class to get this value dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a signal for that.

Create a file `singals.py` in your application.

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Store)
def save_total_price(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.total = Book.objects.all().aggregate(Sum("price"))["price__sum"]
```

Connect your signals in App's Config like so:

```py
# app.py
class WhateverAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "{app_path}"

    def ready(self):
        import {app_path}.signals
```

Now point in `__init__.py` of the app the config like so:

```
default_app_config = "{app_path}.apps.WhateverAppConfig"
```

Other solutions might include cached variable that holds that information (which I think its the better way).

Comment: yes i have try this code i got this error `raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '
ValueError: "<Store: dsg fsf>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Comment: got you, I've understood this wrong I've edited the post. You can now check how to do it.

Comment: yes dear! i hv get an error when i try to save `StoreForm' object has no attribute 'instence'` .

Comment: You have a typo in `instence`. Also where do you get that error?

Comment: signals are not working it's not calculating anything?

Comment: Could you post the code? Also make sure that your signals are firing by adding a `breakpoint()` in them

Comment: which code do you need i will post? i don't understand how and where i add a `breakpoint()`?

Comment: Post your signal code in `singals.py` (assuming that you've created it) put the `breakpoint()` into that signal function django will stop executing right after you save the model and that's how you would understand if its firing. I told you to add it because I think the signal function is not executing.

Comment: yes you are right there is something goes wrong with signals function it's not executing i have post the images of my `signals.py ` and `models.py` code on the top please see this code if you find anything wrong?

Comment: This would certainly not work because of what I explained in my answer pre_save is triggered only when Store object is saved ( not in case new book is added/removed or if Book changed value)
Also whole task seems tedious as you can always annotate() sum

Comment: my logic is if anybody want to buy the books from store i want to know the total price of books that's why i am using this

Comment: i want to use in case if new book is added/removed or if Book changed Value

Comment: Please respond.

Comment: Did you add the default_app_config  in `__init__`? Also please create a github gist with your `signals.py` code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a function in signals with `m2m_changed` i think this is the better way if you want to save the total_price into Database. Thanks to all of you guys for helping me. this code is working for me fine. :)

```
def save_total_price(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    if action in ['post_add', 'post_remove', 'post_clear']:
        books = instance.books.all()
        instance.total_price = 0
        for book in books:
            instance.total_price += book.price
            instance.save()


m2m_changed.connect(save_total_price, sender=Patient.books.through)
```